# Build-A-Bricks Building Set

Tags: building, clone-brands

When I was a boy - 1940's-50's - I had a plastic building set called, Build-A-Bricks, or some such. It was for modeling brick houses. The pieces were similar to LEGO but larger and there were cardboard windows, doors and roof elements. Does anyone remember such a product? Are there any such products on the market now?

Comment: Maybe you can try Bricklink or Brickset? Try this page:https://brickset.com/sets. Click on the drop-down menu that reads "Year".

Comment: @Alfred Welcome to Bricks Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, maybe called Bilda-Brix.

I was given set for Christmas when I was 4.5. This would have to have been 1951.

Don’t remember any instructions, just used my imagination to build houses, towns and even battle ships! They were mostly red, some white hence I could have opposing battle ships. LEGO with its kits to build a specific thing has always seemed to me to demand less of the imagination.

[image: Bilda-brix set box photo]

Comment: This certainly fits the description. Nice work, and welcome to Bricks.SE!